# Xamarin.Forms List bound to ListView sometimes briefly displays elements, then everything disapears

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I followed the documentation from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/styling?pivots=windows) to create a multipage app with a local database that shows short notes. However, this does not follow MVVM. So I attempted to restructure the code to adhere to the MVVM design.

In my App.xaml.cs file I create a NavigationPage to the MainPage, which is a ContentPage that contains the ContentView for the list of notes. I tested whether my notes get loaded properly, by writing them to the debugger, which is working properly. My NotesView.xaml is this:

```
...
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:NotesViewModel />
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView Margin="{StaticResource PageMargin}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"
                                  Detail="{Binding Date}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My NotesViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AwesomeApp.Models;

namespace AwesomeApp.ViewModels
{
    class NotesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public NotesViewModel()
        {
            notes = new List<Note>();
            _selectedNote = new Note();
            LoadNotes();
        }

        private Note _selectedNote;
        public Note SelectedNote
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedNote;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedNote != value)
                {
                    _selectedNote = value;
                }
            }
        }

        List<Note> notes;
        public List<Note> Notes
        {
            set
            {
                if (value != notes)
                {
                    notes = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Notes");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return notes;
            }
        }
        public async void LoadNotes()
        {
            notes = await App.Database.GetNotesAsync();

            foreach (var note in Notes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Notes: {0},{1},{2}", note.ID, note.Text, note.Date);
            }

        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My model Notes contains three properties:

```
public class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        private string text;
        private DateTime date;
...
```

When I now try to display a ListView with items from a List, the items very briefly appear and then disappear. This displaying of the elements only sometimes happen when I rebuild the app when I made layout changes and saved them so that HotReload triggers during debugging on an android 9.0 phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to run/debug your application I found a couple of mistakes which I think are creating these problems.

1- Change the constructor to:

```
public NotesViewModel()
{
    LoadNotes();
}
```

If you want to select a note, do not instantiate a new one as `_selectedNote = new Note();`. The selected note must be pointing to a note on the `Notes` list.

2- In the `LoadNotes()` you have to do:

```
Notes = await App.Database.GetNotesAsync();
```

Keep in mind to always use the property and not the private field. Since you do `notes = ...`, the property is not triggering an `OnPropertyChanged("Notes");`. So you either have to do the:

```
notes = await App.Database.GetNotesAsync();
OnPropertyChanged("Notes");
```

or (better):

```
Notes = await App.Database.GetNotesAsync();
```

3- Your model class, should not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and it should be directly something like:

```
public class Note {
    private int id;
    private string text;
    private DateTime date;
}
```

In any case you have your ViewModel to do such kind of trickery and notify your View about a change in the ViewModel data.

Comment: Thank you, your second point fixed it! I'll have another look at understanding the basics of MVVM.